# Как вывести массив случайных неповторяющихся чисел в определенном диапазоне

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Например нам нужно вывести 10 случайных неповторяющихся чисел в диапазоне от 1 до 15. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Для такого случая идеально подойдёт функция [`random.sample(population, k, counts=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample), где `population` — некоторый интервал/множество, `k` — размер выборки, а `counts` — максимальное количество повторений (по умолчанию 0).

```py
import random
print(random.sample(range(1, 16), 10)) # 16 пишем потому, что последний член
                                       # в range не включается в интервал
# [14, 6, 10, 12, 1, 2, 8, 11, 7, 3]
```